# What are the steps needed to integrate an existing Angular app with an existing .net mvc & .net core application?

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core

What are the steps needed to integrate an existing Angular app with an existing .net mvc & .net core application, where to start?

Comment: That’s a very broad question. How should they be integrated? What’s the relation between them?

Comment: I am using angular as front and .net core api as backend, so i wanted to run the application from visual studio using F5

Comment: You put the javascript files into the project, make the main page load them. Not much more to it

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the options available

1. Integrating Angular and .Net Core with SignalR

   https://code-maze.com/netcore-signalr-angular/
2. Integrating Angular and .Net Core using a REST API over http / https

   https://dev.to/dileno/build-an-angular-8-app-with-rest-api-and-asp-net-core-2-2-part-2-46ap
3. Integrating Angular and .Net Core using SOAP web services

   https://github.com/lula/ngx-soap